# Can I take a google referral URL and see what was searched?

Tags: algorithm, google-search

I use Fastspring.com as a payment provider, which gives me a referral URL as to where a purchase came from.  Many examples look like this:

```
http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macsqlclient.com%2F&ei=FIrjVIrOJ6qIsQTb4IK4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHHh7lm3CncrL4IfwgM1mdD71hQUA&bvm=bv.85970519,d.cWc
```

Is there anyway I can take this url string and figure our what keywords were searched for? Preferably documentation on how to do so as I have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, that is how google makes their money and giving that data away for free would hurt their business. You can take a look at this [article.](http://moz.com/blog/decoding-googles-referral-string-or-how-i-survived-secure-search)